# Can I populate a Python tkinter combobox from a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Coding newbie here, trying to get to grips with Python 3.

Is it possible to populate a tkinter `Combobox` with single word values read from a text file?

What I'd like to do is replace the hard coded values for "fish", "birds", etc (see below), with values read from a text file (each word on a separate line). I've been reading about dictionaries, arrays and so on and all I've done is confuse myself!

Thanks in advance.

This snippet works with hardcoded combo values. How can I change it read the values from a file please?

```
# imports

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Create instance
win = tk.Tk()   

# Add a title       
win.title("Combo Test")


# Creature Drop Down
ttk.Label(win, text="Select Creature").grid(column=1, row=3)
creature_box = tk.StringVar()
creature_chosen = ttk.Combobox(win, width=20, state='readonly')
creature_chosen['values'] = ('Fish', 'Birds', 'Insects', 'Reptiles')
creature_chosen.grid(column=2, row=3)
creature_chosen.current(0)

# Start GUI
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: do you know how to read anything from file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily store these values in a `txt` file and read them from there. Considering that the content of the file is formatted as following:

```
Fish
Birds
Insects
Reptiles
```

you can modify your code as following:

```
# imports
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Read values from file
creatures = []
with open('data.txt') as inFile:
    creatures = [line for line in inFile]


# Create instance
win = tk.Tk()   

# Add a title       
win.title("Combo Test")


# Creature Drop Down
ttk.Label(win, text="Select Creature").grid(column=1, row=3)
creature_box = tk.StringVar()
creature_chosen = ttk.Combobox(win, width=20, state='readonly')
creature_chosen['values'] = tuple(creatures)
creature_chosen.grid(column=2, row=3)
creature_chosen.current(0)

# Start GUI
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: How to do i Add Button which stores the selected value in the combo box for above code and so that I can use this elsewhere in the program.

Comment: @Jake sorry for the delayed response, you can post a question regarding your issue so that more people will be able to see it and help you.